# How to make a JTable editabe with the help of checkbox?

Tags: java, eclipse, jtable, jcheckbox

I changed table model items and make the table non editable. So now, I added  checkbox in order to give an opportunity to the user to edit the table when he select the checkbox. And when the checkbox is not selected, the table should't be editable.

This is the code of JTable and checkbox.

```
 JTable jt12;
    String[] column_headers12={"subject","room","time","group"};
    String[][] student_marks12={{"rights","225" ,"10-00","DG-1"},   {"law","302","12-00","MG-5"},{"kazakh","142","14-00","DG-2"},   {"constitution","105","16-20","MG-3"}};
    JScrollPane js12=new JScrollPane();
    js12.setVisible(true);
    js12.setBounds(0, 11, 454, 163);
    panel_12.add(js12);

        jt12=new JTable(student_marks12,column_headers12);
        jt12.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {"rights", "225", "10-00", "DG-1"},
                {"law", "302", "12-00", "MG-5"},
                {"kazakh", "142", "14-00", "DG-2"},
                {"constitution", "105", "16-20", "MG-3"},
            },
            new String[] {
                "subject", "room", "time", "group"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
                false, false, false, false
            };
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return columnEditables[column];
            }
        });
        jt12.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        jt12.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        jt12.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        jt12.setBackground(new Color(255, 248, 220));
        js12.setViewportView(jt12); 

        JCheckBox chckbxEditMode = new JCheckBox("edit mode");
        chckbxEditMode.setBackground(new Color(255, 228, 196));
        js12.setRowHeaderView(chckbxEditMode);
```

Comment: try firing an event when the checkbox is clicked have a  boolean to keep track of whats happening. example if the checkbox default is unchecked have a false boolean flag, upon click, if flag is false change to true and vice versa. change the editable/non editable status based on that flag

Comment: Update `columnEditables` in your checkbox handler.